# html dropdown list for month

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I would like to ask why the dropdown list for month is not according to what the code said?The dropdown list supppose to show from september to october.

[The screenshot image of the dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvvbO.png)

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="selectmonth" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-1 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-1 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-2 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-2 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-3 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-3 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-4 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-4 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-5 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-5 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-6 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-6 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-7 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-7 month')) ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-8 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-8 month'))?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-9 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-9 month')) ?> </option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-10 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-10 month')) ?> </option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-11 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-11 month')) ?> </option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime('-12 month')) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime('-12 month')) ?> </option>
</select>
```

Comment: The said link is down. Can you embed the screenshot into your question ?

Comment: Link works fine for me. May be you have network problems with cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its done

```
      <select class="selectpicker" id="selectmonth" onchange="myFunction()">
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-1 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-1 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-2 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-2 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-3 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-3 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-4 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-4 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-5 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-5 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-6 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-6 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-7 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-7 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-8 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-8 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y'))))?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-9 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-9 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?> </option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-10 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-10 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?> </option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-11 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-11 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?> </option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("m",strtotime("-12 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))) ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime("-12 Months",strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))); ?> </option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because month is equivalent to 30 days in general and today is 31 October. Technically 31-30 is 1st October, which indeed is October when you echo `date('F', strtotime('-1 month'))`.

```
// while tested in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/. Them seem to have Oct 31 as their system date
<?php echo date('F', strtotime('first day -1 month'));?> //Outputs: October
<?php echo date('F', strtotime('first day -2 month'));?> //Outputs: September
<?php echo date('F', strtotime('first day -3 month'));?> //Outputs: August
```

[Try this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81e5147357ee423ee17e86604b48fdfd804e85bb):

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="selectmonth" onchange="myFunction()">
  <?php for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo date('m', strtotime("first day -$i month")) ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime("first day -$i month")) ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

**Update**
As I browse through, I found following as [working solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1f3debb4cff7ecd003a463fa949eddd105e6044):

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="selectmonth" onchange="myFunction()">
  <?php for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
  $d=new DateTime('now');
  $d->modify("first day +1 day -$i month");
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $d->format('m') ?>"><?php echo $d->format('F') ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: today is the 30th of october

Comment: mine timezone says 31 October :D

Comment: It also depends on the time of the PHP server, not the user's machine.

Comment: prepending "first day " seems to solve the problem mysteriously.